# RealmMigrationNeededException while

Tags: android, realm, realm-migration

I have a live app which uses a previous version of realm(v0.85.1), I'm working on a new release which uses version 4.2.0 of realm and also has a schema change. The schema change is just a single column added to one table. For the Migration I have this class.

```
public class ImRealmMigration implements RealmMigration{
    @Override
    public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {

        RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();

        if(oldVersion == 0){
            schema.get("Layout")
                    .addField("orientation", String.class, FieldAttribute.REQUIRED);
            oldVersion++;
        }
    }
}
```

And in the application class I have this

```
 Realm.init(this);
        RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .name("default.realm")
                .schemaVersion(1)
                .migration(new ImRealmMigration())
                .build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration); // Make this Realm the default

        Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
```

When I go to run the app, it works until the last line where it throws a RealmMigrationNeededException and proceeds to list all the primary keys in the schema saying they have been made optional. Does anybody know why this happens and what I can do to solve it? Here is the stacktrace:

```
                FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
                    java.lang.RuntimeException: 
                Unable to start activity io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: 

        Migration is required due to the following errors:

- Property 'Book.privateId' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'BookType.bookTypeId' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'Cart.id' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'ClipArt.url' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'Contact.userId' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'CreditAccount.id' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'Layout.layoutId' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'LayoutClipArtItem.layoutItemId' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'LayoutItem.itemId' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'LayoutPhotoItem.layoutItemId' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'LayoutShapeItem.layoutItemId' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'LayoutTextItem.layoutItemId' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'OrderSession.id' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'PagePhoto.pagePhotoId' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'Photo.privateId' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'PhotoOrigin.identifier' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'PrintPack.privateId' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'PrintType.printTypeId' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'Product.productId' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'ProductFamilyMarketing.productFamilyType' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'Region.rid' has been made optional.
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3151)
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3261)
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:219)
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1735)
                                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6939)
                                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
                                                                                                        Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Migration is required due to the following errors:
                                                                                                       - Property 'Book.privateId' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'BookType.bookTypeId' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'Cart.id' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'ClipArt.url' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'Contact.userId' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'CreditAccount.id' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'Layout.layoutId' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'LayoutClipArtItem.layoutItemId' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'LayoutItem.itemId' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'LayoutPhotoItem.layoutItemId' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'LayoutShapeItem.layoutItemId' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'LayoutTextItem.layoutItemId' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'OrderSession.id' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'PagePhoto.pagePhotoId' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'Photo.privateId' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'PhotoOrigin.identifier' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'PrintPack.privateId' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'PrintType.printTypeId' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'Product.productId' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'ProductFamilyMarketing.productFamilyType' has been made optional.
                                                                                                       - Property 'Region.rid' has been made optional.
                                                                                                           at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.nativeGetSharedRealm(Native Method)
                                                                                                           at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.<init>(OsSharedRealm.java:172)
                                                                                                           at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.getInstance(OsSharedRealm.java:219)
                                                                                                           at io.realm.BaseRealm.<init>(BaseRealm.java:124)
                                                                                                           at io.realm.BaseRealm.<init>(BaseRealm.java:93)
                                                                                                           at io.realm.Realm.<init>(Realm.java:153)
                                                                                                           at io.realm.Realm.createInstance(Realm.java:424)
                                                                                                           at io.realm.RealmCache.doCreateRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:342)
                                                                                                        at io
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 0.89.0
>
> Breaking changes
>
> @PrimaryKey field value can now be null for String, Byte, Short,
>   Integer, and Long types. Older Realms should be migrated, using
>   RealmObjectSchema.setNullable(), or by adding the @Required annotation
>   (#2515).

See the change log for version [0.89.0](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0890)

You can bypass this easily by adding `@Required` on your `@PrimaryKey` fields.